# Are unfocused browser tabs safe from malware attack?

Tags: browser

Say I have 5 tabs in use in my web browser, all connected to different websites
(my browser is Chromium). Obviously only ONE tab is the focus of use at any one
time. And that tab (webpage) is therefore exposed to malware attack (as is the
case when you visit ANY website).

However, are all the other UNFOCUSED tabs safe from malware attack because
they're not currently being used? Or are they effectively live as well, and
therefore exposed to attack in just the same way that the focused tab is?

If unfocused tabs ARE live, is there a simple way to switch them off (so to
speak), so that they are safe from malware?

I'd like to keep all my tabs in place, and not have to close them when not
in use.

Comment: You are aware that using Linux blocks nearly 99% of malware/spyware viruses...  See [How is Linux not prone to viruses, malware and those kinds of things?](http://superuser.com/questions/195387/how-is-linux-not-prone-to-viruses-malware-and-those-kinds-of-things).  Most attacks in Linux are rootkits, and most users protect their system against these types of attacks.

Comment: If you allow any random web site to run javascript on your computer then you have a security problem whether certain tabs are in focus or not.  On Chromium, install the `NotScripts` extension or similar and only allow javascript to be executed by sites you trust (and even then, only if absolutely required for the site to function - many sites work fine without javascript but will use it if available for additional functionality or bling).

Comment: I think you have a skewed model of how malware attacks work. Are you perhaps under the impression that malware just floats through the internet, looking for website and Browser combos to exploit when they happen to collide?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, unfocused tabs are still potentially running.

It's not impossible that AJAX sites like StackExchange would become compromised, and deliver evil malware instead of delicious notifications.

I wouldn't say this is a big threat to be concerned about at the moment.  Malware is usually delivered immediately when you load the page.  That's what I'd want as a malware author, in control of a website or third-party advert.  Then I wouldn't bother hacking the notification code as well.

This isn't a case the experts have been publicly worrying about (pardon me for saying so but it doesn't sound like you consider yourself one).

I guess the threat to look out for would be some weird XSS bug in AJAX comment notifications on sites running out-of-date blog software, but with pages popular enough to be worth attacking...  I think it's still a very contrived situation, because of the details of that last part.  The attacker is predicting that people still had this tab open, *and the would-be victim has already switched away from the tab before the attack* (and isn't going to switch back to it either!).

If you look, it's easy to find some Firefox extensions that did this.  However they're all described as both experimental and ancient.

I would focus on making sure your browser is up to date and you don't have any third-party plugins (that is: java, and flash without click-to-play enabled).  And if you're anxious that you don't have enough protection, you should have a no-exception ad-blocker (uBlock Origin).  You might like HTTPS Everywhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1: JavaScript in unfocused tabs usually can still run as you can see with ewbsites that raise themselves after some amount of time. So, they are not completely inactive per default.